# qqline connects the first and third quartiles. How do I draw a line between different quantiles (ie 30% and 70%)?

Tags: r, plot

I have a qqnorm plot of a data set with 1000+ points. I want to draw a line between two quantiles at a time (say 30% and 70%) just as qqline does with 25% and 75%, but with the freedom of choosing which quantiles to use. I've poked around with ggplot a bit but can't seem to get something that works. What's the best way to do this?

edit: 
My data are the changes in the dollar to pound exchange rate in the Garch data set of Ecdat:

```
diffbp = diff(Garch[,5])
```

After that, all I'm doing is

```
qqnorm(diffbp)

qqline(diffbp)
```

but I also need plots where qqline can go through different quantiles, for comparison.

edit 2: 
I've tried the following:

```
> qqnorm(diffbp)

> quantile(diffbp,probs=c(0.01,0.99))
       1%       99% 
-0.029850  0.032675 

> qqline(c(-0.029850,0.032675))
```

I don't think the resulting lines are exactly what I'm going for. Namely, I believe that the line always goes through -1 and 1 on the x axis, when I want it to go through the appropriate quantiles.

edit 3: Figured it out! Computed the sample and theoretical quantiles by hand, computed the equation of the line through them, and then drew the line using `abline()`. Rather time-consuming way of going about it, though.

Comment: In case you didn't know, http://stats.stackexchange.com/ can be a helpful resource for R related questions too!

Comment: thanks, it's my first time here so I don't really know where to go

Comment: @Chris Wu - welcome to Stack Exchange. For R-related questions, it is considered good form to offer a small sample of your data and a minimal (i.e. as small as you can make it) example of what R code you have managed to put together already. If your data is proprietary, then consider creating a small set of fake data instead (type ?dput in R-Gui for help on exporting it). If other users can copy the code and data from your question and paste it right into their R installations to experiment with it, the likelihood of you getting a response to your question will increase significantly.

Comment: @AustinHenley CV is not really for generic R questions, which this and the other one on `source()` are. It causes extra work for people you we direct them them to inappropriate sites.

Answer (score 2):

I think you just need

```
qqline(diffbp,probs=c(0.3,0.7))
```

**edit**: I see from the comments on [R: qqline connects the first and third quartiles. How do I draw a line between different quantiles (ie 30% and 70%)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12771988/r-qqline-connects-the-first-and-third-quartiles-how-do-i-draw-a-line-between-d) that the difference is that I am using R-devel, and (as @caracal points out) that this feature is new since R 2.15.1 patched (see http://developer.r-project.org/blosxom.cgi/R-2-15-branch/NEWS , 7 July 2012)

Here's an example that seems to show that `qqline()` works (I used 0.1, 0.9 for greater contrast):

```
set.seed(101)
z <- rgamma(1000,shape=1)
newprobs <- c(0.1,0.9)
## png("qq.png")
qqnorm(z,pch=".")
qqline(z,col="red")
qqline(z,col="blue",probs=newprobs)
## add reference lines
abline(h=quantile(z,c(0.25,0.75)),col="red",lty=2)
abline(h=quantile(z,newprobs),col="blue",lty=2)
abline(v=qnorm(c(0.25,0.75)),col="red",lty=2)
abline(v=qnorm(newprobs),col="blue",lty=2)
## dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: This actually gave me an incorrect line since it wasn't actually going through the desired quantiles on the qq-plot. Thanks, though!

Comment: I haven't looked in detail, but I'm really baffled as to why this doesn't work, and to the suggestion that the 0.25/0.75 quantiles are hard-coded -- the code for `qqline` certainly *looks* like arbitrary quantiles are coded correctly ...

Comment: Ah, versions. Seems to make sense to have added the capability to plot arbitrary quantiles with `qqline`.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:**

The information below is valid for R (and `stats` package) version 2.15.1 - apparently later versions will incorporate the built-in capability of plotting arbitrary quantiles.

---

`qqline` seems to be hard-coded to plot the .25 and .75 quantiles. But if you don't mind creating your own function, something like this might do:

```
myQqplot <- function(data, probs){
  qqnorm(data)
  theQuants <- quantile(data, probs = probs)
  lm1 <- lm(theQuants~qnorm(probs))
  abline(lm1)
  invisible()
}

myQqplot(diffbp, c(.5,.99))
```

[image]

There's no check to make sure that you supply only two quantiles to the `probs` argument, but you could add it if you want.

Comment: @ChrisWu, oh, I see you edited your post to say that you already did what I wrote up here. Didn't see that before posting the above. If you like your solution better, you could post it as an answer and accept it!

Answer (score 1):

Make a new function by copying the code and changing the second line to:

```
x <- qnorm(c(0.30, 0.70))
```