# R: qqline connects the first and third quartiles. How do I draw a line between different quantiles (ie 30% and 70%)?

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [qqline connects the first and third quartiles. How do I draw a line between different quantiles (ie 30% and 70%)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766253/qqline-connects-the-first-and-third-quartiles-how-do-i-draw-a-line-between-diff)

I have a qqnorm plot of a data set with 1000+ points. I want to draw a line between two quantiles at a time (say 30% and 70%) just as qqline does with 25% and 75%, but with the freedom of choosing which quantiles to use. I've poked around with ggplot a bit but can't seem to get something that works. What's the best way to do this?

I've found a function that seems to do what I want, called plot.qqline in the package sma. Unfortunately, this is a really old package and is now deprecated. However, that's the type of functionality I'm looking for.

edit: Figured it out!

Comment: R version 2.15.2 (scheduled for October 26) will allow this: [help on qqline](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/qqnorm.html) -> option `probs`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Is there any workaround I could use in the interim?

Comment: Just install [R-2.15.1-patched](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rpatched.html) (assuming you need the Windows version), or use `panel.qqmathline()` from the `lattice` package.